# Nodemon error "Internal watch failed"

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting this error in my Node.js console:

```
[nodemon] Internal watch failed: watch /home/dell/Downloads/Adaani5.0 
(copy).0/node_modules/engine.io/index.js ENOSPC
```

For it, I have run two commands after an Internet search:

**First:**

```
       ps -ef | grep node

        sudo kill -9
```

**Second:**

```
  echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 |      sudo tee --append 
  /etc/sysctl.conf&&      sudo sysctl -p
```

And the error persists.

Comment: did you reboot after changing number of watches?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo nodemon
```

Resolved for me. Or login to Root user.